# Custom statuses not displayed for playa within a matrix field

Tags: matrix, playa, status

I'm having an issue with displaying custom statuses in my playa-within-matrix field.

I'm looking at an entry (on the front end) that has 4 matrix rows with a related entry in each. 3 of the related entries have a "Paid" status and one is "open".

Using this code, I only see the one entry with the open status:

```
{matrix_field}
  {playa_field}
    {title}
  {/playa_field}
{/matrix_field}
```

Which is fair enough, but if I add the status parameter I still see no entries, even if it's just status="open". ie both of these show no entries:

```
{matrix_field}
  {playa_field status="open"}
    {title}
  {/playa_field}
{/matrix_field}

{matrix_field}
  {playa_field status="open|Paid"}
    {title}
  {/playa_field}
{/matrix_field}
```

I'm on EE 2.4.0 with Matrix 2.5 and Playa 4.3.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were some parsing issues in Matrix in 2.5 for fields that had parameters.

Seeing as how you say that when using {playa_field status="open"} causes no entries to display leads me to believe that you're affected by that one.

Upgrade Matrix to the latest version (2.5.2 currently) and that should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks! I should have thought to update Matrix as well, I assumed it was a Playa issue. I updated to 2.5.2 and all is well.